# Multiple CGPoints to CGRect

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I have a a set of `CGPoint`s which represent a shape which is a bit like an upside down 'T' shape, now I want to convert those points into a `CGRect` which fits inside the shape, so to create a `CGRect` which encompasses the entire shape I just loop through and work out the lowest `x` and `y` for the top left and the highest `x` and `y` for the bottom right which is great but leaves white areas outside of the image, how could I figure out the largest rectangle without white areas so the final shape is more like an '|' shape? My code so far:

```
CGPoint topLeft = CGPointZero;
CGPoint bottomRight = CGPointZero;
for( NSValue *value in points ) {
    CGPoint point = [value CGPointValue];
    if( topLeft.x == 0 || topLeft.x > point.x ) shapeRect.x = point.x;
    if( topLeft.y == 0 || topLeft.y > point.y ) shapeRect.y = point.y;
    if( bottomRight.x < point.x ) bottomRight.x = point.x;
    if( bottomRight.y < point.y ) bottomRight.y = point.y;
}
CGRect shapeRect = CGRectMake(topLeft.x, topLeft.y, bottomRight.x - topLeft.x, bottomRight.y - topLeft.y);
```

EDIT: I've drawn some pics to show what I'm trying to achieve. Grey areas show the `CGRect`.

Here's the image shape, I have coordinates for each point in the shape:

[Image Hosted by ImageShack.us http://img684.imageshack.us/img684/121/crop1.png](http://img684.imageshack.us/img684/121/crop1.png)

Here's what my code above produces:

[Image Hosted by ImageShack.us http://img26.imageshack.us/img26/2521/crop2j.png](http://img26.imageshack.us/img26/2521/crop2j.png)

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

[Image Hosted by ImageShack.us http://img689.imageshack.us/img689/5499/crop3.png](http://img689.imageshack.us/img689/5499/crop3.png)

Comment: Are the lines in the shape always either vertical or horizontal?

Comment: Also, would the — shape at the bottom be an equally valid answer to the same problem? (It would also be a rectangle that fits within this shape.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I did not misunderstand the question, your aim is to find the blue points: 
[image]

If I'm correct, then it's enough for you to store two points (say `topL` and `topR`) and a value (say `bottom`).

[image]

Iteratively:

- check if the current point has `y < topL.y` and eventually update `topL` and `topR`.

  - If instead `y == topL.y` check if current `x` is less than `topL.x`. If yes update `topL`
  - otherwise check if current `x>topR.x`; if yes update `topR`.
- check if current `y>bottom`. If yes update `bottom`.

Note that when I say "update `topL`" I mean both `x` and `y`.

At the end you can get your bottom-left and bottom-right points using `x` coordinate of `topL` and `topR` and setting `y` coordinate to bottom.

Answer (score 5):

Hard to get a grip on what you are actually asking about. In regards to the title this function will create the smallest rect for any number of CGPoints.

```
CGRect CGRectSmallestWithCGPoints(CGPoint pointsArray[], int numberOfPoints)
{
    CGFloat greatestXValue = pointsArray[0].x;
    CGFloat greatestYValue = pointsArray[0].y;
    CGFloat smallestXValue = pointsArray[0].x;
    CGFloat smallestYValue = pointsArray[0].y;

    for(int i = 1; i < numberOfPoints; i++)
    {
        CGPoint point = pointsArray[i];
        greatestXValue = MAX(greatestXValue, point.x);
        greatestYValue = MAX(greatestYValue, point.y);
        smallestXValue = MIN(smallestXValue, point.x);
        smallestYValue = MIN(smallestYValue, point.y);
    }

    CGRect rect;
    rect.origin = CGPointMake(smallestXValue, smallestYValue);
    rect.size.width = greatestXValue - smallestXValue;
    rect.size.height = greatestYValue - smallestYValue;

    return rect;
}
```

Can be used like this

```
CGPoint poinstArray[] = {topLeft, bottomRight};
CGRect smallestRect = CGRectSmallestWithCGPoints(poinstArray, 2);
```

Answer (score 3):

Swift version of hfossli (it works great !) :

```
func pointToRect(pointsArray: [CGPoint]) -> CGRect {
    var greatestXValue = pointsArray[0].x
    var greatestYValue = pointsArray[0].y
    var smallestXValue = pointsArray[0].x
    var smallestYValue = pointsArray[0].y
    for point in pointsArray {
        greatestXValue = max(greatestXValue, point.x);
        greatestYValue = max(greatestYValue, point.y);
        smallestXValue = min(smallestXValue, point.x);
        smallestYValue = min(smallestYValue, point.y);
    }
    let origin = CGPoint(x: smallestXValue, y: smallestYValue)
    let size = CGSize(width: greatestXValue - smallestXValue, height: greatestYValue - smallestYValue)
    return CGRect(origin: origin, size: size)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want, you can use Core Graphics:

```
let path = CGMutablePath()
path.addLines(between: [p1, p2, p3, p4])
return path.boundingBoxOfPath
```

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully you're only talking about this one shape, always oriented this way, otherwise this becomes a tricky computational geometry problem (something like the largest enclosed rectangle in a concave polygon).

Given your list of points, the following should work:

1. a. Find the point with the largest *y* value.
   b. Find the other point with an equally large *y* value.
   c. Compare the *x* values of these two and determine which is leftmost.
2. Find the minimum *y* value of all the points.
3. Create two new points, each with an *x* value equal to one of the points you found in step 1, and with the *y* value found in step 2.
4. The two points from step 1 are your top left and right points, and the two created in step 3 are the bottom left and right. You can now construct the final rectangle.